# How to pass request URL to mailto body

Tags: html, url, mailto

I need to pass URL to the body part of the mailto link. 
Sample URL :

```
www.test.com?param1=value1&param2={value2}
```

If i pass this URL, it's cut down after the '&'. So, i have tried to encode the URL like below:

```
www.test.com%3Fparam1%3Dvalue1%26param2%3D%7Bvalue2%7D
```

It works, but the URL is not readable. How can we achieve this without encoding or showing readable URL in the mail body?

Comment: People will be more willing to help you if you go back and accept answers to some of your previous questions.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But, i am not seeing any link to accept answers, can you route me?

Comment: Click the check mark next to the answer you feel is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When is doubt, read the specification:

http://shadow2531.com/opera/testcases/mailto/modern_mailto_uri_scheme.html

Validator available at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 1):

Try this bit of code:

```
<a href="mailto:?subject=this is a subject&body=[sub]" onclick="this.href =this.href.replace('[sub]',window.location)">Send Mail</a>' with current webpage (offline mode will send file location on disk).
```